# Selecting Best Features in a feature vector using Adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

I've read some documentation on how Adaboost works but have some questions regarding it.

I've also read that Adaboost also **picks best features from data** apart from **weighting weak classifiers** to and use them in testing phase to perform classification efficiently.

**How does Adaboost pick best features from the data?**

Correct me if my understanding of **Adaboost** is wrong!

Comment: Adaboost assigns weigths to classifiers, so the classifier with maximum weight is the one who classifies best. But you shouldn't use this as a rule, because all classifiers are supposed to be weak and only slightly better than random uniform classifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases the weak classifiers in Adaboost are (almost) equal to features. In other words, using a single feature to classify can result in slightly better than random performance, so it can be used as a weak classifier. Adaboost will find the set of best weak classifiers given the training data, so if the weak classifiers are equal to features then you will have an indication of the most useful features.

An example of weak classifiers resembling features are [decision stumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_stump).

Comment: Are there any more cases where features and classifiers are the same. How to identify those when you look at a feature vector?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to find the most useful features?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand adaboost algorithm. I have read many research papers. Many authors have interchangeably used the terms  "features" and "classifiers". I was wondering if this was so in most of the cases or just a special few. I want to know how did authors come to such a conclusion.

Comment: Could you refer to these articles where they use different terminology?

Answer (score 1):

OK, adaboost selects features based on its basic learner, tree. For a single tree, there are several means to estimate how much contribution a single feature does to the tree, called relative importance somewhere. For adaboosting, an ensamble method, containing several such trees, the relative significance of each feature to the final model can be calculated by measuring significance of each feature to each tree then average it.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: After creating a stump from the feature that gives least Gini impurity, do we consider the same feature again in subsequent stump creation?